# How to change the style/display of dateRangeInput with R/Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

[Edit]

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible:

server.R :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$body_UI<-renderUI({
tabPanel("Comparison",
         {
           fluidPage(
             fluidRow(
               box(
                 width=12,
                 solidHeader=T,
                 title="Parameters",
                 status="primary",
                 uiOutput('date_range_UI')
               )
             )
           )
         }
)})     

  output$date_range_UI <-renderUI({
    dateRangeInput(
                   "date_1",
                   "Period 1",
                   start=NULL,
                   end=NULL
                   )
    })
}
```

ui.R:

```
uiHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = NULL)

  uiSidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput('sidebar_UI'))


  uiBody <- dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css"
      ),
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style_v2.css")
    ),
    uiOutput('body_UI')
  )

  dashboardPage(uiHeader,
                uiSidebar,
                uiBody,
                skin = "black")
```

I think that my problem comes from the file style_v2.css :

```css
.progress-bar, .irs-bar,.irs-bar-edge, .irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single{
background-color:#000033;
}

.box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header
{
  background-color:#000033;
}

.box.box-solid.box-primary{
  border: 1px solid #000033;
}

.box.box-primary, .nav-tabs-custom>.nav-tabs>li.active
{
border-top-color:#000033;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content-wrapper, .right-side{
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  background-color:#333;
}
```

This file is located in the folder 'www' which is in the same directory than server.R and ui.R.

If I delete this file, then I have no problem. But I need it and I don't know which part is causing this.

---

I'm trying to insert a period field using dateRangeInput (Shiny).
But I'm having problems in the display.

NB: I encounter the same problem using dateInput.

Here is an extract of server.R:

```
dateRangeInput(
               "date_1",
               "Period 1",
               start=min(data$Date_processed),
               end=""
               )
```

This is completely illegible...
[image: display_problem]

Comment: Your first move should be to consult the help for the function. See `?shiny::dateRangeInput`. The documentation states: "end: 
The initial end date. Either a Date object, or a string in yyyy-mm-dd format. If NULL (the default), will use the current date in the client's time zone". An empty string is therefore not a valid value. You probably want to pass NULL instead.

Comment: Your `min(data$Date_processed)` must also be a proper Date (try `class(data$Date_processed)`, it should say `Date`) or a string in format "yyyy-mm-dd". It probably is, but it is impossible to check without data.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answers. I don't think that my problem is coming from the arguments (especially start/end). I've already tried `dateRangeInput("date_1", "Period 1", start=NULL, end=NULL )`, but the problem is always the same

Comment: NB: The empty string allows to have no default value, while NULL gives the current date.

Comment: Ok, my bad then!

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? `dateRangeInput` works fine so the problem is somewhere else! A minimal reproducible example with `uiOutput` in UI and `renderUI` in the server, etc.

Comment: FYI I tried my best to break the `dateRangeInput` by passing rubbish as the start and end date and it still always work, so the problem is indeed with how you call it. Do you still see the problem if you visualise the app in chrome or firefox?

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my post. I think that the problem comes from a .css file which defines the style. I am a beginner with all that.
The problem is still the same with Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this piece of code in your style_v2.css file:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

`#333` is the dark background you are seeing. You can either remove this or edit the hex colour to be lighter.

If that code is necessary for other dropdowns in your code you can be more specific regarding your css - let me know.

Comment: Ok, I deleted these lines from the .css file and now it's perfect. Thank you so much !

Comment: Sure, glad to help!